# 400 invalid_request error in google social login using Socialite

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-socialite

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
    {

       $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
       $rootFolder = null;

    \Storage::extend('google', function($app, $config) use ($user, $rootFolder) {
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId($config['client_id']);
    $client->setClientSecret($config['client_secret']);

    $client->refreshToken($user->refreshToken); // user's refresh token

    $service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
    $adapter = new GoogleDriveAdapter($service, $rootFolder); // user's root folder ID
    return new \League\Flysystem\Filesystem($adapter);
  });

    dd(Storage::disk('google')->listContents('/', true));
   }
}
```

output:

400. That’s an error.

Error: `invalid_request`

Missing required parameter: `client_id`

Learn more

Request Details
That’s all we know.

Comment: Your answer is in your error ! you are not passing/ passing null or empty parameter for required client_id. 

For your help , follow exactly this one 

https://medium.com/employbl/add-login-with-google-to-your-laravel-app-d2205f01b895

Answer (score 0):

```
$client->setClientId($config['client_id']);
```

This part. did you set your client id in .env file? and don't forget to `php artisan config:cache` after you add a new value to .env file.

Comment: This is my env fileapp_name="videoapp"
client_id=****
client_secret=****
api_key=****
redirect=http://localhost:8000/login/google/callback

Comment: can you print out the ```$config['client_id']);```?